# Check AWS Cloudfront invalidation complete time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, invalidation, cache-invalidation

I would like to know **at what point in time a given Cloudfront invalidation has been completed**.

When browsing invalidations in AWS Console, I can only see `Date created` timestamp, as per attached image.

[image]

I would like to know what is the date of completion. Couldn't find any info in the docs, also [aws cli](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudfront/get-invalidation.html) `get-invalidations` api doesn't say anything about it.

Is it possible at all?
Basically what im trying to achieve is to measure how much time my invalidations take, so I can assertain if this is the cause of tests failures in my project.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Get Invalidation API call, call it repeatedly, and note down the time status switched to 'Completed'.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/latest/APIReference/API_GetInvalidation.html

If you're using boto3, you can use a waiter.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudfront/waiter/InvalidationCompleted.html

If you've got Enterprise support, get your TAM to submit a feature request, or a +1 on an existing feature request if one exists.  (At this point (Dec 2023), I'd guess the feature request surely exists).

Answer (score -1):

As per AWS:- [Invalidate the Amazon S3 objects](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serving-outdated-content-s3/#:%7E:text=Object%20invalidations%20typically%20take%20from,distribution%20from%20the%20CloudFront%20console.)

> Object invalidations typically take from 10 to 100 seconds to complete. You can check the status of an invalidation by viewing your distribution from the CloudFront console.

Comment: Thank you for your input but this does not answer my question. Unless you are saying that what i'm asking for is impossible.

Comment: AWS will not tell you the exact time of how long the invalidation takes because it can varies on different factors. AWS gives you the approximate range as mentioned by aprit above .

Comment: @NSS OP isn't asking in advance!  Once an invalidation has completed, that information is available (to AWS), since the status of the invalidation changes to 'Completed' at some point in time.  They just don't make it available via any API call.  (sounds like a good candidate for a feature request).